# Как написать регулярное выражение для обработки каждого второго вхождения?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть две строки

> price-new">123131 ,
>   price-old">2123423

как написать регулярку, чтобы цена бралась только от price new и при этом пропускала значение price-old?

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("price-new\">(\\d+)"); - не то?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так [пример](https://regex101.com/r/p2UWCh/1): `(?<=price-new">)(\d+)`